# How to create ZFS mirror with disks of different sector sizes?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, zfs, mirroring

Trying to repair a mirror in a ZFS pool:

```
louis@watson:~$ sudo zpool status
  pool: watson
 state: ONLINE
  scan: resilvered 1.55T in 7h22m with 0 errors on Fri Oct  6 03:19:16 2017
config:

NAME                                            STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
watson                                          ONLINE       0     0     0
  mirror-0                                      ONLINE       0     0     0
    wwn-0x50014ee0ad3655a3                      ONLINE       0     0     0
    ata-Hitachi_HUA723020ALA640_MK0271YGJA5BSA  ONLINE       0     0     0
  wwn-0x50014ee058480994                        ONLINE       0     0     0
```

When I try to add a disk I get the message "*devices have different sector alignment*":

```
louis@watson:~$ sudo zpool attach -f watson wwn-0x50014ee058480994 scsi-SATA_ST2000DM001-1CH_Z1F2ZSLP
cannot attach scsi-SATA_ST2000DM001-1CH_Z1F2ZSLP to wwn-0x50014ee058480994:
devices have different sector alignment
```

Here are the sector repots from the new and target drives:

```
 louis@watson:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_ST2000DM001-1CH_Z1F2ZSLP | fgrep Sector
        Logical  Sector size:                   512 bytes
        Physical Sector size:                  4096 bytes
        Logical Sector-0 offset:                  0 bytes
 louis@watson:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x50014ee058480994 | fgrep Sector
        Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
           *    SCT Long Sector Access (AC1)
```

How can I mix these drives in one pool?

Comment: Add it manually, but you'll loose performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume it relates to [this check](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/4435) (details copied from user *DeHackEd*):

> The main purpose is a sort of "force" command for when you have a pool created with ashift=9, then you try to replace/attach a disk with 4k sectors. ZFS doesn't like this (and with good reason) so specifying -o ashift=9 overrides sector size detection and makes ZFS take it.
>
> [...]
>
> No, the requirement is that ashift_of(inserting_disk) <= ashift_of(existing_vdev). Failure to do so will result in EDOM being returned and the operation not proceeding. The inserting_disk value is read from the disk itself, but can be overridden with -o ashift=value with a value satisfying the inequality above to make ZFS accept the disk.
>
> The rationale is that attaching a disk with too big an ashift will result in such staggeringly bad performance (for rotational media anyway) that users will be unhappy. I've done it, my 500G (half filled 1TB drives) mirror took 24 hours to resilver when should have been 2 hours. It was caused by mixing 512 and 4096 byte sector drives.
>
> [...]
>
> Other way around. The pool had ashift=9 but inserting a disk with 4k sectors (ashift=12) results in the inequality 12 <= 9 which is incorrect. Using zpool ... -o ashift=9 makes it 9 <= 9 and ZFS accepts it.

So, you can append your disk by using `sudo zpool attach -o ashift=9 -f watson wwn-0x50014ee058480994 scsi-SATA_ST2000DM001-1CH_Z1F2ZSLP`, but your performance may suffer. The alternative would be to recreate the pool with correctly-aligned disks, or to not mix and match sector sizes (which means using different disks).

Comment: Great find! Promising... will try once the back up is complete.

Comment: Been having trouble with the backup. Mind taking a look at this?
 https://serverfault.com/questions/882591/more-accurate-way-to-obtain-zfs-filesystem-size

Comment: This works! Resilvering seems slow at 50 MB/sec. But this is a legacy box with few users, so definitely a cost/effort win. :)

Comment: @user121391 So, the process of adding 512 byte to an existing 4096 byte should work just fine?  I have a 4k mirror set with ashift of 0 and a couple of 512 disks that individually mounted with ashift of 0 (via "zpool get all").  I want to create a 4-disk 0/1 set with these.  Will it work reasonably well?